# Set date with form for calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm using a CalendarHelper from here http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised

It displays the current month, which gets picked up like this:

```
class XyController < ApplicationController
@date ||= Date.today
```

I would like a form in the view, so I could set this date to any custom date.
Something like this:

```
  = simple_form_for(@date) do |f|
    = f.input ???
```

I think I'm missing the main point how to set up a form for an instance object, maybe.
How could I implement a form to set a date for an instance variable which I set in the controller?

Edit.:

**calendar_helper.rb**

```
module CalendarHelper
  def calendar(date = Date.today, &block)
    Calendar.new(self, date, block).table
  end

  class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
    HEADER = %w[Hétfő Kedd Szerda Csütörtök Péntek Szombat Vasárnap]
    START_DAY = :monday

    delegate :content_tag, to: :view

    def table
      content_tag :table, class: "calendar" do
        header + week_rows
      end
    end

    def header
      ...
    end

    def week_rows
      ...
    end

    def day_cell(day)
      ...
    end

    def day_classes(day)
      ...
    end

    def weeks
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

in the view:

```
  = calendar do |date|
     = date.day
```

So in the helper there is date = Date.today, i would like to change this to a @date instance, and would like to set that in a simple show view, eg.:

**profiles_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @date ||= Date.today
end
```

And in the view like:

form_for(@date) do |f|
    f.date_select :date

Something like this, but this obviously isn't working nor correct

Comment: Hi, can you show controller and view code?

Comment: Controller doesn't matter. I only want to set a date field, in a form in a show view, the as a params[:date], or similar, reload the page and and set a @date variable with it. And I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the form for this feature, you can use Javascript:

```
# view
<%= select_date(@date, {}, onchange: 'reload_with_date($(this))') %>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
  # this function will get the date selected
  # and reload the page with the params[:date]
  window.reload_with_date = function(select_tag) {
    var date = Date.parse( $(select_tag).val() ); # get the selected date
    var current_url = window.location.href; # get the current URL
    if(current_url.indexOf('?') > -1) { # if already GET params in URL
      window.location.href = current_url += '&date=' + date.toString();
    } else { 
      window.location.href = current_url += '?date=' + date.toString();
    }
  }
<% end %>

# controller
def calendar
  @date = params[:date] || Date.today
  # will set @date to Date.today if params[:date].nil?
```

Documentation about select_date:

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_date

Don't hesitate to ask about this if you need. Hope this helps!

Comment: You are welcome! You can also take a look at the *very nice* datepicker function included in jQuery UI: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that something similar to this would work

```
#view
= simple_form_for(@date) do |f|
  = f.input :date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.date_select(:dob,:start_year => 1950) %>
```

this should work for you. This is how I wrote in `.html.erb` you can write it your way. But this is how a date picker can be generated.

Comment: `= form_for(@date) do |f|
    = f.date_select(:date, :start_year => 1999)`

Gives me this: undefined method `model_name' for Date:Class

Answer (score 0):

Using `form_for` with a variable is used to [bind a form to an object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object), meaning each field of the form corresponds to a field of the object.

For instance, let's say you have a user field with a username and a age field, you could do the following :

Controller

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

View

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.text_field :age %>
<% end %>
```

The username and age fields will automatically be set to the values of the current user.

Now, for your case.

(I'm relying on the old calendars episode on railscast here : http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars )

If your form is logically bound to an active record, you can use the `calendar_for` helper as if you were using a `form_for` helper.

So if your object is a user :

```
calendar_for @user, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use a normal `form_tag` helper without an object bound to it, and use the `calendar_date_select_tag` helper for inserting your calendar.

More infos on this helper [in the docs](https://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/wiki/CalendarDateSelectParameters)

Feel free to ask any follow up questions.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach:

```
- if @user.content_date
  %br/
  = f.text_field :content_date, id: 'datepicker', size: 10
  %br/
```

with this id being used to pick it.